# How to jump to friend's comment on video or photo

Tags: facebook, comments, friends

On Facebook, in the **news feed** you can see when friends place a comment on a video or photo. However, what that friend has written is not shown directly, which is annoying when the video or photo has thousands of comments.

How can I jump to, or directly view, what that friend in particular has written? I.e. How can I avoid having to click `show more comments` a billion times and then ctrl+F'ing my friend's name?

Comment: +1. I'd like to know if there is a way. But i seriously doubt it. The only thing i could figure out was to click on "previous comments" and hit Ctrl+F to find my friend's name.

Comment: @AbhishekGirish That is currently how I do it, but you can only load comments in 50s. Last time I spent like 10 minutes clicking to load the comments (with the page scrolling all the way to bottom each time) only to find out my friend actually removed his. I'm never doing that again.

Comment: Agree. But 've not been able to find a better way. Sometimes visiting the person's profile shows his recent activity. If you are lucky, you can find that. But again, if its been a while its of no use sometimes since more comments might have piled up.

Comment: +1 I've got the same question. Now I load all comments and search for the name of my friend by Ctrl + F. The dumbest and the only way!

Answer (score 1):

After much fidgeting about with Facebook's markup, I believe I have found a way.

For all the situations I have tested it in, this method has worked. So here's how you can get a link to a specific comment:

Below every comment in Facebook, is a little stamp that tells you when the comment was posted.

[image]

As circled above, if you right click on that time stamp, and then pick `Copy link address` (in Google Chrome) or the equivalent in other browsers, you will then have the link to that specific comment.

Now paste the copied link into your URL bar and you will see the window scroll to that comment and the same comment will be highlighted for a few seconds.

From a technical perspective, if you are interested in knowing how this works, read on...

Every comment in Facebook has a `comment_id`. If you add the `comment_id` for a specific comment into the query string in the URL, you will see that comment get highlighted.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood my question, but this is not what I meant. I meant when you are reading your **news feed**, when you see `X has commented on a video from Y` and that video has thousands of comments, you have a hard time finding the comment your friend `X` has posted.

Comment: But you could solve the problem if you had the link to that comment?

Comment: Yes, but **finding** it is the problem here!

Comment: There may be another way. Have you tried using the activity log?

Answer (score -3):

Clicking <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+the notification solves the problem.

Comment: There's no notification, it's on the news feed.

Answer (score -3):

I just found out how to do it; you've got to right click on the notification and click 'copy link address', then paste it onto the address bar.

Comment: There's no notification, it's on the news feed.